# Erro Handlers ASp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Pessoal preciso de ajuda com o item abaixo.

O erro está ocorrendo ao tentar rodar um projeto Web Site em VB.Net. Tenho dois na mesma *solution*, um roda e o outro aparece esse erro. É um projeto da empresa que trabalho, não fui eu quem construiu estou entrando no projeto agora para poder realizar ajustes no código e implementações.

Procurei por diversos soluções e nada até o momento.

Segue o erro:

> Erro HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error A página solicitada não pode
>   ser acessada porque os dados de configuração relacionados à página são
>   inválidos.
>
> Informações detalhadas sobre o erro: Módulo IIS Web Core Notificação
>   BeginRequest Manipulador Ainda não determinado Código do erro
>   0x80070021 Erro de Configuração Esta seção de configuração não pode
>   ser usada nesse caminho. Isso ocorre quando a seção está bloqueada em
>   um nível pai. O bloqueio é por padrão (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), ou
>   é definido explicitamente por uma marca de local com
>   overrideMode="Deny" ou o allowOverride="false" herdado. Arquivo de
>   Configuração
>   \?\D:\WorkSpace_QuestManager\QuestManager\questmanager_solution\questmanager_webapps\questmanager_survey\web.config
>   URL solicitada
>   http://localhost:80/questmanager_survey/survey.aspx?cod=962bc469-95d7-46f0-8f3e-0faa2515d4ca&cpc=0&cod4=156
>   Caminho físico
>   D:\WorkSpace_QuestManager\QuestManager\questmanager_solution\questmanager_webapps\questmanager_survey\survey.aspx
>   Método de logon Ainda não determinado Usuário de logon Ainda não
>   determinado
>
> Origem da Configuração
>
> 169: modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
>
> 170: handlers>   171:

Comment: Sua pergunta está bastante confusa. O que você está tentando fazer exatamente? Que situações levam o erro a ocorrer?

Comment: Oi Victor, editei o post. O erro está ocorrendo ao tentar rodar um projeto Web Site em VB.Net. Tenho dois na mesma solution, um roda e o outro aparece esse erro. É um projeto da empresa que trabalho, não fui eu quem construiu estou entrando no projeto agora para poder realizar ajustes no código e implementações.